# Meaning of "..." in Python function signature

Tags: python, documentation

In the language reference, I've seen "..." used in multiple places for function parameters without an explicit specification for how it should be interpreted.

```
map(function, iterable, ...)
```

for [maps](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#map)

```
class C:
    @classmethod
    def f(cls, arg1, arg2, ...): ...
```

for [classmethod](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#classmethod)

```
class C:
    @staticmethod
    def f(arg1, arg2, ...):...
```

for [staticmethod](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#staticmethod)

I feel like the second and third are merely informally saying that the signature of the function is unspecified when using "..." but I am confused with the usage in maps. I know *args specifies variable number of positional arguments, what does the ellipsis mean in this case?

Comment: The ellipsis inside the brackets is indicating varargs (`arg3`, `arg4`, `arg5`, `...`), the one outside just means "here be the function implementation".

Comment: @jonrsharpe so "..." in function body is like pass? also I thought *args (or some other identifier) was used to indicate variable number of arguments

Comment: this is not actual python code, just pseudocode showing how functions can be called.  The `...` means "you could call this with more arguments as appropriate".  Similarly the `...` in place of implementation means "this is where the implementation is".  This syntax is useful for documentation but is not functional python.

Comment: The documentation doesn't contain actual signatures (note also the `[]` for optional arguments), see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/introduction.html#notation.